# Feedback survey modal on window close event after 10 exits, irrespective of same or different user

Tags: javascript, numbers, bootstrap-modal, feedback, surveymonkey

I am a newbie to it, so please bear with me.
I am looking to set up a feedback survey in Survey Monkey but would like a pop up box (modal) to appear when users exit the website.
Ideal requirements:
Ideally I’d like the pop up box to appear for approx. 1 in every 10 visits to the site. (either close or refresh window tab), using javascript / jquery.
Seeking for expert advice.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [popup website collector](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Website-Collector). Either the `Popup Invitation` or `Popup Survey type`. Just choose the `Website` collector type when creating a new collector for a survey.

Looking at the help page and the options it doesn't seem to have the options to set how often the popup shows up. You may be able to modify the embed code to set when and how often it pops up but I'm unsure about that.

You can give it a go or contact SurveyMonkey support if you're having trouble.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers,but as per my search with it, it doesn't serve our requirements as such. I am also looking if it can be done with Javascript as a standalone(cookies/counting number of clicks-actions by same user at a time & browser exit action for popular desktop browsers.) Please guide me if I am missing something. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

just to give an update, we used the reference link: http://beeker.io/exit-intent-popup-script-tutorial

to implement as per our requirements, by setting cookies for each user instead of users count. Hope this will help to someone. Thanks